# Create topic using java - kafka version >0.10.0.0

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to write java api to create kafka topic . I have Kafka version 0.11.0.0 . I searched in stack overflow and tryied the same way. But it is always giving me exception no matter topic exists or not.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
 org/apache/kafka/common/errors/TopicExistsException
 at kafka.admin.AdminUtils.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala)
 at kafkaStream.Processor.CreateTopic.main(CreateTopic.java:65)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
 org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

I tried following code:

```
            String topicName = "t5";
            String zookeeperHosts = "XXXX:2181,XXXX:2181"; 
            int sessionTimeOutInMs = 15 * 1000; 
            int connectionTimeOutInMs = 50 * 1000; 
            Properties topicConfig = new Properties();
            zkClient = new ZkClient("XXXX:2181,XXXX:2181", 
                    sessionTimeOutInMs, 
                    connectionTimeOutInMs, 
                    ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$); 
            zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, new 
            ZkConnection(zookeeperHosts), false);
            ZkUtils.apply(
                    "XXXX:2181,XXXX:2181",
                    sessionTimeOutInMs,
                    connectionTimeOutInMs,
                    false);
       //     AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topicName, numPartitions, 1, 
          topicConfig, RackAwareMode.Enforced$.MODULE$);
            AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topicName, 2, 1, new 
          Properties(), RackAwareMode.Enforced$.MODULE$);
```

maven dependencies ->

```
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
       <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
       <version>0.11.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
       <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
       <version>0.11.0.0</version>
       </dependency>
```

Comment: Have you added dependent api (kafka-clients of specific version) jars to classpath?

Comment: yes i have added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the new 0.11.0 version I suggest to use the new Admin Client API (following link for some documentation : https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html).

Using Zookeeper for doing such operations will be deprecated in the future pushing the usage of the new Admin Client API.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i tried with AdminClient. I am not able to do. Can you please share any example

Comment: You can find a really simple example here (and you just need the kafka-clients dependency, see the related pom.xml) : https://github.com/ppatierno/kafka-playground/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/playground/CreateTopic.java

Comment: Thanks a lot @ppatierno, I was facing issue becoz of importing wrong package. Thanks a lot

Comment: There is no error to call createTopics method, but after that it is giving me error                                                        java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.

Comment: becoz of it, topic is not getting created

Comment: it seems to be a problem connecting to the Kafka cluster. Can you try to use the kafka-topics.sh tool for that with a command like this : `kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic test`. At least you can try if the cluster is reachable even if the current tool uses Zookeeper (not used by the Admin Client API which connects directly to a broker).

Comment: Yeah, I am able to create using kafka-topics.sh tool

Comment: adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(topic)); 
 is having exception   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException: The request 
 attempted to perform an operation on an invalid topic.

Comment: Thanks you so much ppatierno, it is working. I am able to create topic using rest API, there was some issue in the way values coming from UI, it was appended with ''' .

Comment: Happy you found the reason, I couldn't know about that :)